# Django/Python models - multifield options

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say I created a Model `AnObject`, and one of the fields would be `shape`. If I have 3 sets shape types that the model could be, circle, square, triangle. What is the best way to write out the model? Let us assume that these shapes are not models (so no foreignkey field should be used here) themselves, they are just shape types.

```
class AnObject(models.Model):
    shape = ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to use the `choices` argument for a particular field. Documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices)

Thus:

```
class AnObject(models.Models)
    SHAPE_CHOICES = (
        (CIRCLE, 'Circle'),
        (TRIANGLE, 'Triangle'),
        (SQUARE, 'Square'),
    )
    shape = models.CharField(max_length=8,
                             choices=SHAPE_CHOICES,
                             default=CIRCLE)
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured it was something like that. Now would this be best practice in the case of only 2 choices? Or should I use a boolean instead and name one true and name the other false?

Comment: It's probably a matter of personal preference, but I think I would still go with a `CharField` listing out the options. It makes it more easily expandable in the future if you do decide to add a third option. That being said, you could use a boolean if you knew you wouldn't add other options later and there is a clear default, to the point you would reasonably ask "Is your object a Circle?" with a 'Yes/No' field.